# Installing a 3-way switch

Tags: electrical

I have a two wire switch (old house) with no ground wire. I want to replace with a three way switch there and across the room. Is this a possibility?
[image]

Comment: Is pulling cable an option? What wiring method was used for the existing wiring?  Can you get us a photo of the inside of the existing switch box?

Comment: Sorry, had family emergency. Hope you're still around. Pulling cable is a possibility just concerned how existing wiring runs. It appears to run to light fixture first, then branches out to switch and outlets from the light.

Comment: Are you sure it's running to the light fixture first?  It looks like it hits the switch first and then the light from the inside of the switch box...

Answer (score 3):

From your statement it sounds like knocking out plaster and fishing some 14/4 cable is out of the question.

Yes, but you'll need a very particular smart switch to do it.

First, the smart switch must work without neutral, and you must partner this with bulbs it can do that with.  Incandescents work of course, CFLs are a dead technology, and only certain LEDs like to work with no-neutral smart switches.

Second, the smart switch will need to support and work with a wireless remote switch, either battery operated or powered by whatever power you can get to that location.  Presumably the remote switch would use radio to communicate with the controlling switch.

There are a variety of smart products on the market like this, specifically because people like you have problems like these.  We're not a "shop for me" site (the info goes stale too fast for our encyclopedic format) so I can't be much help picking brands.

It sounds like trying to pull /3 or /4 Romex would be a real problem for you. For what it's worth, the rules for running low-voltage wiring are easier.  If you can manage to get thermostat wire to the switch locations, you could use low voltage either for a relay controlled switch circuit or just for the *entire* lighting circuit.  LEDs are so efficient that you can get usefully bright light from low voltage LED "bulbs".